# Convert docker container dates to milliseconds since epoch

Tags: date, docker

I'm trying to find long-running docker containers.

First running `docker ps --format '{{.RunningFor}}'` returns something like

```
About a minute ago
11 minutes ago
```

which is completely useless for machine processing. 
I couldn't find any way to change this, and the same value is in JSON output.

Next I tried `docker ps --format '{{.CreatedAt}}'`. This returns values like `2019-01-03 12:49:46 +0000 UTC`.

Problem is this isn't ISO 8601 nor any other common format. What's worse, trying to parse it with `date` gives:

```
date --date="$DATE"
date: invalid date ‘2019-01-03 12:49:46 +0000 UTC’
```

I expect there has to be a better way to get an epoch milliseconds value, than processing the value manually with `awk` etc, but I can't find it. 
Best thing would be a function like `{{epoch .CreatedAt}}` (similar to `{{lower .Name}}`)

Comment: Best workaround so far: `echo $DATE | sed 's/ +0000 UTC/+00:00/'` makes it `date` read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `docker inspect <container-name>` which gives you detailed infos about one  container.

You might be interested in the value of **State.StartedAt**

```
 "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1234,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-12-20T12:41:54.281709415Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2018-12-20T12:41:28.781748517Z"
        },
```

To inspect all running containers you could execute:

```
docker container ls --format="{{.Names}}" | xargs -n1 docker container inspect
```

**JSON output**: Having [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) installed (`apt-get install jq`), you can filter just the container name and the StartedAt with

```
docker container ls --format="{{.Names}}" | xargs -n1 docker container inspect | jq '.[] | {name: .Name, uptime: .State.StartedAt}'
```

**CSV output:** (semicolon separated, sorted by age)

```
docker container ls --format="{{.Names}}" | xargs -n1 docker container inspect --format='{{.Name}};{{.State.StartedAt}}' | sort -k2,1
```

**EDIT:**

using `docker ps`
(This is assuming that creation time = start time. Which doesn't work if you stop and start containers. docker ps only gives `RunningFor` and `Status`, both in human readable "5 weeks ago" style. It's more reliable to use `docker inspect` method to get the actual runtime.)

```
docker ps --format="{{.CreatedAt}} {{.Names}}" | sort -k1,1
```

**EDIT2:**

It turns out, that you can do all this with go and the docker api.
Here is a simple demo I just coded:

You could grab the binary [link](https://github.com/m1d1/docker-container-age/releases/download/1.37/container_age):
Or change the code to your liking and compile it by yourself [link](https://github.com/m1d1/docker-container-age)

The result will look like this:

```
container_age for API v1.37
DURATION ID         NAME
50h      1234567890 /jenkins
362h     1234567891 /elasticsearch
```

Comment: That's not ideal, but it works. So there is no way to convert the values returned from `docker ps`?

Comment: added **EDIT** part to my post, using `docker ps`

Comment: problem is the `docker ps` command still gives the non-parsable date format of `2019-01-04 10:47:54 +0000 UTC`

Comment: Thanks for the go program, I wish I could upvote the answer more than once.  However in practice it's easier to use docker cli + xargs (which are already installed) than deploying and managing a custom utility like this. However it's a nice point that you can always go the API way if all else fails

Comment: Does these timestamps from inspect always give nanosecond data? Or does it depend on the system?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to someone here is a bash script I put together based on [the anwser by Michael D.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492291/183837)

```
        before=$(date -d"$SINCE" +%s)

        while read -r id started
        do
          milis=$(date -d"$started" +%s)
          if (( before > milis ))
          then
            echo "$id"
          fi
        done < <(docker ps -a --format="{{.ID}}" | xargs -n1 docker container inspect --format='{{.ID}} {{.State.StartedAt}}') \
        | xargs docker rm -f -v
```